# Visual Studio 2022 keeps adding white space on string with backticks in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022 keeps adding white space on string with backticks in JavaScript code

```
return `
    <div class="text-nowrap">
        <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
    </div>
`;
```

When I format the document (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D), an extra white space will be added to the code as below.

```
return `
        <div class="text-nowrap">
            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
        </div>
    `;
```

The extra white space will keep adding as long as I press (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D).

```
return `
            <div class="text-nowrap">
                <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
            </div>
        `;
```

How can I prevent it?

Comment: I don't exactly get what's the issue .

Comment: Hi @PaperPLane. When I press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D to format the document, the string inside backtick ` keep go to rigth because the white space keep adding. How to prevent it?